# How do I run a Powershell script from a second Repository in a different Build?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to have a centralized repo for some Powershell scripts that I want to share with multiple Builds and Releases.

I wanted to have a Powershell Task that calls one of those scripts in a Build. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I run a Powershell script from a second Repository in a different Build?

The answer is yes.

You could add a `command line` task in the build pipeline of first Repository to clone the second Repository by the git command line:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

git clone <repo> <directory>
```

With this task, we cloned the powershell scripts to current default working directory, then we could execute this powershell scripts.

Then add add powershell task to call one of those scripts in a Build, in the **Script Path**, we need to specify the path like following:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<SecondRepositoryName>\<PSFolder>\TestPS.ps1
```

Note:

When you use git clone   to clone the repo, you need to provide your certificate in your source link, usually using PAT:

[image]

The link looks like:

```
https://<OrganizationName>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/Test
```

Then we need to replace the first OrganizationName with PAT. So, it will be:

```
https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/Test
```

As test, it works fine on my side, you can check if it works for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for Azure Artifacts. Take a look on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops

Comment: I was looking at that but my question is how do I bring in that artifact and call a certain Powershell script from that artifact in a Build task?

Comment: take a look to the section: Package and send the module
Basically you'll add a powershell task, restore a module from your private feed and use it into your pipeline

Comment: Is there an alternative? I am not that familiar with creating Powershell modules. That documentation seems a little over kill for the small script I am trying to have run for all my builds.